# Converting string to timestamp issues sql

Tags: sql, presto

I'm trying to cast a string to timestamp but I'm getting the following error:

`Failed to output to file. Query failed: Value cannot be cast to timestamp: 2020-03-23T05:17:44.000Z`

I'm using the query below:

```
select CAST(purchase_date AS timestamp)
from main_table
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [from_iso8601_timestamp](https://prestosql.io/docs/current/functions/datetime.html#from_iso8601_timestamp) function if timestamp with time zone type is acceptable.

Or, you can use [date_parse](https://prestosql.io/docs/current/functions/datetime.html#date_parse) function.

Answer (score 0):

Try `parse_datetime()`:

```
select parse_datetime('2020-03-23T05:17:44.000Z', '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%i:%s.%fZ')
```